# Is there any way to do pass message in IOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am new to IOS, I worked on windows, there we have a concept message passing, using which we can send any message to any instance and get the work done. Likewise is there any way here in IOS?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Objective-C was founded based on the notion of sending messages to objects.  In fact...I think **every** object-oriented language is based on sending messages (i.e. calling methods) on objects to get work done.  Could you be a lot more specific?

Comment: Say for ex: A have method funA() and B have method funB(). f If I want to call the method funA() from  class B and funB() from call class A, basically this type of call will leads to cyclic dependency. But objective C based on sending messages, is it ok here to call like that.

Comment: A cyclic dependency?  From a design standpoint?  There is no programmatic problem with that logic in any language that I am aware of.

Comment: In windows if we try to compile that kind of code we need to include others .h lib references, so it will not compile successfully because each one depends on other. To make this kind of call we will use message passing.

Comment: "In windows"?  Windows is not a language.  Anyway, that is what "forward declarations" are for (they also exist in C++).  You don't need to know anything about the methods of a class in the header file, so only import it in the implementation (.m) file.  This will eliminate the circular import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feroz,
Objective - C by default supports message passing, i.e. when you do something like this

```
[self calculateSum];
```

here you are passing message `calculateSum` to `self`.

Then objective-c runtime calls the method `calculateSum` on `self`.
For further you can read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C#Messages) and [this](http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/macsploitation/bypassing-objectivecs-message-passing-mechanism-for-speed-24946)

Answer (score 0):

In Cocoa there's a concept that enables you to listen for and send notifications - `NSNotification`. A method (selector) can register it's interest in certain messages and be triggered when some part of the code send that message.

[Notification Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Introduction/introNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000043i)

Sending and receiving notifications are also similar to Key-Value Observing where you register for changes of property values.

[KeyValueObserving.html](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html)

*...maybe this what you are searching for*